# Is there any apis to initialize my custom class object with llvm transformation pass?if not what is the best strategy to achieve this?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm implementing a llvm transformation pass.And in some point ,I need to initialize my custom class object and call its methods.
Let's say for example:

```
 Foo* foo = new Foo(3);                   
 foo->createSomething(attrCount, foo)
```

i need to insert these instructions.What should I do?
I think i have to use AllocaInst and then create a function call with IR Builder.But I couldn't able to get it down till now.

Answer (score 0):

Not expert to LLVM or Clang, yet I do not find out any LLVM-official api you can use for such suitation, but I think there is a indirect way that may be helpful to solve your problem.

AFAIK, you should insert the instructions like those in IR emitted by clang. It may be troublesome because you need to process some symbols, like `Foo`, `new` and `createSomething`.

`llvm::TypeFinder` would be useful to find a specified "class" type, actually class type are represented as StructType, you can getName to find the type you need.

For a function, normally you need the name of it to getFunction, but names are mangled in IR, so you should get the mangled name of the function first. LLVM does not provide such interface to mangle a name, as I know, so you have to do it manually. For example, `clang_Cursor_getMangling` in libclang could be able to get the mangled name in AST (getting an AST is quite easy in libclang lol).

Finally, the last step is use `IRBuilder` to create some instructions to do the big job, such as `CreateAlloca`, `CreateCall`, and so on.

Hope this helps.